# Episerver sorting order of pages should not effect website pages sorting order

Tags: episerver

When i am sorting order of the pages in Episerver, its affecting the website also. means website pages are also changes sorting order.

how we can sort order of pages in episerver in a way that it should not affects website page sorting order.

Is there any configuration or settings in episerver?

Comment: Why would you structure your pages in the edit mode differently from how you want them represented in menus on the site?

Comment: currently the behavior is when editors sort the articles in episerver edit mode. its changes sorting of articles in website also.In website i want only to show the latest first article

Comment: Alright, then post the code where you select the articles.

Comment: I make it work like added OrderByDescending(x =>x.StartPublish) in my query.so it will always returns latest articles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a `PageDataCollection` you use the `FilterSort` class

Example

```
// your pages
PageDataCollection _newsPageItems;

FilterForVisitor.Filter(_newsPageItems);
new FilterSort(FilterSortOrder.PublishedDescending).Filter(_newsPageItems);

// The _newsPageItems are now filtered and sorted
```

This is the standard way of sorting and securing listed information from Episerver, also read the article [Searching for pages based on page type](https://world.episerver.com/documentation/developer-guides/CMS/search/Searching-for-pages-based-on-page-type/)

Considering you use the DataFactory to fetch a list with pages you can build a PageDataCollection from a `Enumerable<PageData>` object instance

Also using the `DataFactory` is bad practice and you should be using `FilterForVisitor` as well. My recommended implementation would be

```
// Construct an IContentLoader, this can also be done using Dependency Injection
var loader = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IContentLoader>();

// Get the children of your reference
var children =  loader.GetChildren<PageData>(pageLink, LanguageSelector.AutoDetect(true));

// Construct new PageDataCollection and filter for visitor
var sortableChildren = EPiServer.Filters.FilterForVisitor.Filter(children);

// Sort
FilterSort sortFilter = new FilterSort(FilterSortOrder.CreatedDescending);
sortFilter.Sort(sortableChildren);
```

Comment: I am using DataFactory, the code is

List<PageData> children = 

DataFactory.Instance.GetChildren(pageLink, LanguageSelector.AutoDetect(true)).Where(c =>c.CheckPublishedStatus(PagePublishedStatus.Published)).ToList();

Comment: Its compilation error at last line sortFilter.Sort(sortableChildren);

its says,

cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<EPiServer.Core.IContent>' to 'EPiServer.Core.PageDataCollection'

Comment: Simply create a PageDataCollection `var sortableChildren = new PageDataCollection(EPiServer.Filters.FilterForVisitor.Filter(children).ToList());` or skip the FilterSort and sort your pages using linq `children.OrderByDescending(x => x.Created)`